# Using Dir Command, how do I display the file location on the same line as the file name?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory

When I am trying to find a file on a drive, I type something like:

```
dir /ogn /a /s | findstr /i the_file_im_looking_for
```

The result looks something like:

> 1/1/2019 9:15am 3,783 this_is_the_file_im_looking_for.txt

Problem is, that doesn't tell me where the file is located.

Of course, without the `findstr` command the location of the file would be used as a header for the list of files in that location.

Is there a way to find not only the file by name, but also the location of the file?

Comment: you could use `dir` in conjunction with a `for /f` loop, which will display the full path of each matching files as your parameter. https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html

Comment: Did you notice the `/B` option when you read the output from `Dir /?`? I'd suggest that you add it, and also include 'not directory' with option `/A`, i.e. `/A-D`.

Comment: You could of course just use `Dir` directly with `"the_file_im_looking_for"` whilst rooted at your chosen location, e.g. `Dir "C:\the_file_im_looking_for" /B/S/A-D/OGN` should return the full path locations of any found in the `C:` drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [`forfiles`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html):

```
forfiles /m *the_file_im_looking_for* /s /c "cmd /c echo @path"
```

- `/m` introduces the glob pattern to search for
- `/s` makes the search recurse to subdirectories
- `c` introduces the command to run for each matching file
- `@path` is substituted with the full path of the file

This will print all files and directories which match the glob pattern. As [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) pointed out in comments, if you want to restrict this to files only, you can add a condition to the command:

```
forfiles /m *the_file_im_looking_for* /s /c "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE echo @path"
```

Comment: That's simply beautiful. Thank you!!